# Unable to custom edit menus of webview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui

I used this method to custom edit menus of WebView in UIKit and it works perfectly, but it doesn't work in SwiftUI. What's wrong?

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

class CustomWebView: WKWebView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        switch action {
        case #selector(copy(_:)):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomWebView  {
        return CustomWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

struct WebView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!))
    }
}
```

[image: Result]